# R/ R Studio install.packages('tidyverse') epic installation

Tags: r, tidyverse, install.packages

I'm trying to install this package on a brand new setup of my Laptop W10/64, downloaded brand new RStudio  1.1.419  (as of today 1/28/2018), didn't do anything to profiles. 
After running `install.packages('tidyverse')` I see a lot of dependencies errors like below, how to take care of them in one shot ? I assume should be some dependencies helper in install? Or there is other way to download 1G of R packages to have them all? Or should I have take of these missing brooms one by one? I did my home work and see so many thing about installation problems, assume this is OK for free version.

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘callr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'rlang', 'utf8' are not available for package 'pillar'
* removing 'C:/Users/Lap10/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/pillar'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Lap10\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\Lap10\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8g3UW7/downloaded_packages/pillar_1.1.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'rlang', 'tidyselect' are not available for package 'dbplyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Lap10/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/dbplyr'
Warning in install.packages :
```

After going on missing packages I have this:

```
install.packages('rlang')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Lap10/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘rlang’
  These will not be installed

library(rlang)
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Lap10/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/rlang/libs/x64/rlang.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
```

session info:

```
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.5.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5     R6_2.2.2         assertthat_0.2.0 DBI_0.7          tools_3.2.2      tibble_1.3.0    
[7] Rcpp_0.12.10    
>
```

Comment: Could you copy the results from running `sessionInfo()` in the console?

Comment: New computer, new installation of RStudio, is there a specific reason you're  going with a version of R that's almost two years old vice R-3.3 or R-3.4? Frustratingly, packages for older versions of R are not always maintained or available. I'd be more concerned if this problem remained with a more up-to-date version of R.

Comment: Tx all, @r2  , looks like I might have older install of R, if I download R Studio, should I  have then download R separately ?

Comment: @Brandon session info posted, Tx muchas

Comment: @MarioTrento, it's better to install latest version of R to avoid package issues and installing R after Rstudio is like wearing underpants after jeans, no issues but still not advised.
Also, please check whether `rlang.dll` exist in specified path or is it permission issues on windows ?

Comment: updated to most recent R-3.4  and all problem solved !!!!! Tx @r2 and all again. I assumed that Rstduio has most modern R bin too. M